# Custom URL Scheme with BroadcastReceiver not working (ERR_UKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, url-scheme

I'm trying to use a custom url scheme, myapp://recv in order to receive logins. I figured I would use a `BroadcastReceiver` for this and an `intent-filter`. I went ahead and did this, but no matter what I do, I get the error `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. Googling showed that this used to be a Chromium bug (which has apparently been resolved), and I can't figure out how to solve this. This is my registration of the Broadcast receiver. Thanks!

```
<receiver
            android:name=".LoginReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
                <data android:host="recv"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: You don't usually use schemes, or `Uri` patterns, with a receiver. Who is actually supposed to be sending this broadcast?

Comment: The Twitter API would be redirecting the user to that URI scheme, but whenever it redirects (or I go to it manually), it fails.

In addition, even if I move this intent filter to an activity, it fails.

Comment: "The Twitter API would be redirecting the user to that URI scheme" -- not via a broadcast, they wouldn't. "In addition, even if I move this intent filter to an activity, it fails" -- I'd start by getting rid of your `pathPattern`, since you are not using it. Beyond that, please explain **completely and precisely** what you are doing that causes you to "get the error `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`". Saying "no matter what I do" is not especially helpful, as we have no idea what you tried, what sort of Java stack trace was generated, etc.

Comment: I apologize. There was no stack trace generated. I set myapp://recv as my callback for Twitter, and when it logs in, it should redirect to myapp://recv. Chrome tells me it could not load the page for the reason ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

Comment: If I had to guess, they're not expecting a redirect to be anything other than a regular Web URL.

Comment: No, they allow custom URIs. It's just failing to register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you can't have a URI scheme `intent-filter` going to a `BroadcastReceiver`. It must be an `Activity`.